How I can override portrait orientation lock mode in swift?
I am developing a camera app in Swift and I want it to rotate according to the device orientation, even when the portrait orientation lock mode is turned on via the control center. I noticed that the WhatsApp camera behaves this way: if you press the camera icon, the camera adapts to the device orientation regardless of the portrait orientation lock.
Details:
Objective:
Override the system's portrait orientation lock in my camera app, so the app can rotate freely according to the device orientation.
Current Behavior:
When the portrait orientation lock is on, my camera app stays in portrait mode and does not adapt to device orientation changes.
Expected Behavior:
My camera app should rotate and adapt to the device orientation, similar to WhatsApp's camera functionality.
Environment:
Xcode 15
iOS 17
Swift 5.8
Implementing supportedInterfaceOrientations and shouldAutorotate methods in my view controller.
Adding device orientation observer and manually rotating the view based on device orientation.
Searching for similar questions and solutions, but could not find a working solution.
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

I tried to use this methods in my full implementation but it if the the portrait orientation lock is on it didn't rotate at all

You can read the gyroscope using the CoreMotion APIs and then you can determine how the phone is oriented, then rotate the views manually.

Yeah actually CoreMotion was the solution. Thanks
